# Multiple Ajax loading indicators on 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 2 separate forms that can be submitted via Ajax (jQuery). For each of these forms I'd like to show a loading indicator to the user. I have found a nice piece of code that can easily show these icons, but it only works when there's 1 form.

```
$('.ajaxloader').hide().ajaxStart(function () { 
    $(this).show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

ajaxloader is a class which shows the loading image as a CSS background image. To use it, I just need to add something like: `<span class="ajaxLoader">Busy ...</span>`

When I test this with my page (that has 2 forms), and I submit one of the two, then both loading indicators appear (which is quite obvious). Now my question is, how can I show the indicator that needs to be shown? I was thinking about giving the span-tag an id attribute, but then I don't know how to proceed. I want this to be as generic as possible, so I don't have to hardcode and duplicate code a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: have u checked this??? http://apeatling.wordpress.com/2006/01/18/multiple-ajax-loaders/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attach the "show loading indicator" callbacks to the Ajax queries themselves, not do a 'catch-all' like your current solution.

Something like this in your `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax("/form1/target", {
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".ajax-loader-1").show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $(".ajax-loader-1").hide();
    }
});
```

(And a similar one for your second form, wherever the Ajax call for that is defined)

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about starting it when your form is submitted and hiding the other.

```
$('.yourSubmitButton').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.ajaxLoader').show();
});

$('.ajaxloader').hide().ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

So the loader will show inside the form that has just been submitted (I assume you are doing a submit with a button or a link?) then both are hidden again when the ajax request stops.

Comment: Showing the loading indicator on click of the submit button wouldn't guarantee that the Ajax request has actually started, so it wouldn't make sense to show the indicator just yet. (Maybe some client-side validation has prevented the form from being submitted.)